# Ubuntu 23.10 crashes after resume from suspend

Tags: crash, 23.10

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 x86-64.
I close the laptop lid to suspend. When I open the lid, after a minute or so, Linux puts up a picture of an unhappy computer, saying "Oh No! Something has gone wrong."
It then kills everything I was running, and logs me out.

I have not seen anything crash Linux in many years. This is very disruptive.

[image]

Thanks for the suggestion! (There is LOTS of "logvomit"!)
I think I tracked it down to the gnome-extension dash-to-dock. If I disable it, no crash. If I enable it, gnome-shell crashes after closing & opening the laptop lid.
https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/2124

Answer (score 0):

First step is to put a pin in the timestream with

```
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp
```

Then, do your suspend thing. When your system is usable again,

```
sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
```

This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`. Some messages relate to your problem.

Don't post logvomit ("here's my guess at all the data - you figure it out").
Do not post the whole log file! 99+% of the log entries are not of interest. Use an editor (on  a copy of the file), and keep ONLY the error entries, plus a few lines before and a few lines after. You should end up with a max of 50 lines, and probably fewer than 50. [Edit] your question to add information,  and use the formatting tools.