Gnome tweak tool crashes ubuntu 24.04LTS with Gnome v46
Gnome tweak tool causes "Oh no! something went wrong" message. Rebooting system etc wont fix the issue!
This happen when I:
Run tweak tool > select Appearance > change Cursor from Yaru to something else.

@graham FYI, I just ran into exactly the same issue when I tried to change the cursor as described (specifically the Whiteglass cursor). My Gnome session crashed immediately with the same error dialog as in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492834/ubuntu-23-10-crashes-after-resume-from-suspend and was crashing every time upon logging in. I don’t think there is more to add to this question but maybe it could be phrased better. This is bug #2062377

The fix is released now for 24.04.

I fixed the problem by resetting the mouse cursor back to default using the terminal. I'm also using Ubuntu 24.04 with GNOME 46.
At the login screen:

Switch to a terminal. With CTRL + ALT + F2, for example. I suppose you can also boot in recovery mode and pick the terminal option there.
Run gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme. This will reset the problematic cursor theme back to default. While I was at it, after resetting I checked to make sure and gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme returned 'Adwaita', so I was good to go.
Reboot. Just type reboot.

After that, I could log back in as usual. I noticed running gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme now returned 'Yaru' instead of 'Adwaita', but still, problem solved. This does not solve the bug at the root of the problem though, so avoid changing it again until it is fixed.

Fixed the issue!
by running terminal mode with CTRL + ALT + F3, then type user name/password then run the command dconf reset -f /org/gnome/ ...will reset all gnome related settings including customization.. wallpaper etc, but fixes gnome to work as normal again.

In my case it was the dconf reset -f / rather than ... /org/gnome

I was able to fix it by opening a Wayland session from the login screen (after selecting your account, select Ubuntu Wayland in the bottom right menu), then going back in Gnome Tweaks and restoring the cursor back to “Yaru”.
After logging out and selecting the non-Wayland session, I was able to login again without the error.
For the record, this is bug #2062377.

I experienced this problem too last week, when I tried changing it to the red cursor. I was so terrified when GNOME instantly puked and I started seeing the "Sad PC" death screen EVERY TIME I logged in with the GUI until I ran the first command mentioned here (the one that nukes all your preferences, not the one that only changes the cursor back without messing up my font scaling, wallpaper or imported Outlook calendars).
GNOME tries to be stable in Noble Numbat (impossible)

So unfortunately I encountered this problem today.  I found that logging into Wayland and using the command prompts from Wayland worked best for me.  Everything else I tried did not.  Just in case someone has trouble. To find Wayland, select your username and click the gear at the bottom right corner of your screen.  When the Menu pops up you can choose Wayland Ubuntu and log in from there.  Then by accessing your terminal, you can fix gnome tweaks if it refuses to load like it did for me.  I uninstalled GNOME tweaks btw.  If you are looking for something that makes things pretty try Variety.  It has a lot of nice features.
